# ERROR Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync o my project

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart

Hello i need help trying to fix this error when i run my flutter project it cant run propely then on the terminal show this eror

> /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:85:20: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Codec' doesn't allow null.
>
> - 'Codec' is from 'dart:ui'.
>   Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(
>   ^

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasted a lot of time to solve this, in the end I solved it by uninstall flutter and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is another easier solution for it. i had the same errors, when i downgrade the version of the flutter it has fixed. If someone have this problem and see this answer. You may save too much time with tryinh this  :))